# Java Calculator wrong operator prompt

Tags: java, calculator

i have a calculator class and i want the operation input to be specific to these strings "+, -, /, *" if its not, i want to print a message to enter the operator again.
and please if someone would lessen my code please do it. thanks

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Calculator1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    String operation;
    Double fnum, lnum, answer;
    System.out.println("Enter first Number: ");
    while (!num.hasNextDouble())
    {
        num.next();
        System.out.print("Enter first Number: ");
    }
    fnum = num.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter Operation: ");
    //HERE IM BEING CONFUSED
    while (!num.equals("+, -, /, *"))
    {
        num.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Operator: ");
    }
    operation = num.next();
    //End
    System.out.println("Enter Second Number: ");
    while (!num.hasNextDouble())
    {
        num.next();
        System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");
    }
    lnum = num.nextDouble();




    switch (operation) {
    case "+":
        answer = fnum + lnum;
        System.out.print("Equals= " + answer);
        break;
    case "-":
        answer = fnum - lnum;
        System.out.print("Equals= " + answer);
        break;
    case "*":
        answer = fnum * lnum;
        System.out.println("Equals= " + answer);
        break;
    case "/":
        answer = fnum / lnum;
        System.out.println("Equals= " + answer);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("wrong operator");
        break;


    }
}
```

}

Comment: `!num.equals("+, -, /, *")` <- This will not work or rather will not do what you want it to do. You have to actually check if the entered operation equals none of those operators by hand instead of just writing them into one large string and expect java to figure out what you actually want to do. Also: **num is a scanner**!  A scanner is never equal to a String anytime.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What happens when you debug, and step through the code?  What is the error?

Comment: `num` is a `Scanner`. It will never equal a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to use operators with SWITCH sentence.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    double v1,v2;
    String v3;

    System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
    v1 = num.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
    v2 = num.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter operation [+]   [-]   [*]   [/]: ");
    v3 = num.next();

    System.out.println( ("+".equals(v3) ) ? Operators.ADD.calculate(v1, v2) : "....");

    }

public enum Operators {
    ADD;

    double calculate(double x, double y) {
        switch (this) {
            case ADD:
                return x + y;
            default:
                throw new AssertionError("Unknown operations " + this);
        }
    }

}
```